# Euler substitutions - indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

See please https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Let us look at the most general indefinite integral

$$\int f(x) dx \tag{1} $$ where $x \in D$ and $D$ is some interval.

It is my understanding that to do any substitution $$x = \phi(t)$$
in $(1)$, it must be the case that $\phi(t)$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing i.e. that $\phi$ maps in a bijective manner some interval $D_1$ into the interval $D$ and then of course $x$ takes values in $D$.

In other words to have a valid substitution, the derivative **$\phi'$

must be either strictly positive or strictly negative in the whole interval $D_1$**

But in the first Euler substitution, it is not always the case that

$$\phi(t) = \frac{t^2-c}{b-2t\sqrt{a}}$$
has either a positive or a negative derivative (for all values of $t$).

*So... why for this substitution there is no additional requirement which would ensure that?

I mean... in this sense is it a valid substitution in general?

I assume it is after being checked by so many people. But why?*

I guess the same question applies to the other two Euler substitutions, but I haven't yet calculated $\phi'$ for their cases. I wonder if for the other two substitutions $\phi'$ is strictly positive/negative, or it is but only under certain conditions, and I wonder what these conditions are. I will check that.

But let's say my question is ONLY about the first substitution in particular.

Comment: This is the consideration for the definite integral in $(a,b)$, the substitution should be increasing or decreasing in $(a,b)$. Indefinite case $(a,b)$ is not available.

Comment: @ZAhmed No, I think you're missing my point. The question has nothing to do with definite integrals.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fich, Ch. VIII, §1, 268], a substitution of a variable in an indefinite integral is based on a *local* rule of a differentiability of a composite function at a point. Namely,  if $\int g(t)dt=G(t)+C$  then $\int g(\omega(x))\omega’(x)dx =G(\omega(x))+C$, provided functions $g(t)$, $\omega(x)$, $\omega’(x)$ are continuous. This straightforwardly follows from an equality

$$\frac {\partial d}{dx} G(\omega(x))=G’(\omega(x))\omega’(x)= g(\omega(x))\omega’(x),$$
taking into account that $G’(t)=g(t)$.

I copied a more detailed explanation and an example from [Fich] [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82pwi.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnWrl.png).

*References*

[Fich] (Grigorii Fichtenholz, *Differential and Integral Calculus*, v. II, 7-th edition, M.: Nauka, 1970 (in Russian).